# Can I use Pearson's correlation coefficient or Spearman's rank correlation coefficient as metrics for multi-class time series classification?

Tags: time-series, classification, pearson-r, spearman-rho, multi-class

I am doing a 3-class time series classification problem, where classes are 0,1 and 2. For example, the test set is `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]` for 22 consecutive days, and the prediction is `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.

I think we usually use accuracy, Macro-F1 and Micro-F1 score as metrics for multi-class classification tasks. (recommendation ahout some other useful metrics for multi-class classification is welcomed)

I am reading the book Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading by Stefan Jansen. He uses IC (information coefficient) as metrics, which is measured as the Spearman rank correlation. However, from the parts I have read in this book, IC seems to only appear in time series regression tasks (there might not be many classification tasks in this book though). He has used IC in S&P 500 prediction, which is a time series regression task.

So my question is, can I use Pearson's correlation coefficient or Spearman's rank correlation coefficient as metrics for multi-class time series classification? For example, the above case?

PS: In my problem setting, I set 0 to represent index decreasing comparing to the last day, 1 to be small movements, and 2 to be ascending.

Comment: Spearman's rank correlation requires you to rank the observations of your variable. How would you rank the categories?

Comment: @Dave In my problem setting, I set 0 to represent index decreasing comparing to the last day, 1 to be small movements, and 2 to be ascending. So 1 is kind of between 0 and 2?

Comment: Then it sounds like you have an ordinal regression problem, not a classification problem. Also important, however, is that you seem to be needlessly binning continuous values. Why are you interested in predicting the bin instead of the movement itself?

Comment: @Dave I am doing a stock movement prediction task. Usually it is a binary classification problem in machine learning papers, where 0 represents decreasing and 1 represents increasing (For example, https://aclanthology.org/2020.emnlp-main.676.pdf). I think there are random movements so added it to 3 classes. I don't do regression tasks because for regression tasks machine learning models such as LSTM tend to give historical data as output which makes no sense to real world trading problems.